# MSDN terminology - Window procedure for the predefined control vs the control procedure

Tags: windows, winapi, msdn, internals

### In a nutshell

Confused between the term "The window procedure for the predefined edit control window class" and "the edit control procedure".

### In detail

I feel silly to ask this, but am I missing something from what is mentioned below?

from: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775456(v=vs.85).aspx)

> **The window procedure for the predefined edit control window class**
>   carries out default processing for all messages that **the edit control
>   procedure** does not process. When the edit control procedure returns
>   FALSE for any message, the predefined window procedure checks the
>   messages and carries out the following default actions.

<sup>*</sup>*bold formatting by me*

**Let me specify my interpretation of above:**

**The window procedure for the predefined edit control window class:** I believe this is the internal implementation of edit control's logic inside Windows (similar to any custom control we create).

**The edit control procedure:** Well this is something which I'm not able to interpret accurately. My wild guesses are:

1. Likely: It's our custom WndProc that we *may* subclass from edit control if we need to modify edit control default behaviour (say tab/carriage return processing etc.)

   - My self debate: In this case MSDN would have mentioned word "subclass" explicitly at least somewhere in article.
2. Unlikely: It's some abstracted/specialized internal Wndproc for windows that is class specific.

   - My self debate: If this was the case, there would be some mention of this somewhere.

What further adds to the confusion is the "**When the edit control procedure returns FALSE for any message, the predefined window procedure checks the messages and carries out the following default actions**" mentioned above. I believe the return value from a `WndProc` is always `LRESULT` and is message specific, and this TRUE/FALSE thing applies generally to DialogProcs. So what's the piece I am missing? Also even if I believe its a WndProc, return value does not decide the default processing, our explicitly calling `DefWindowProc()`/`CallWindowProc()` decides the default processing. So what is the return based processing above page talks about?

Comment: Agreed, it doesn't make much sense.  A rough guess is that they are talking about internal code that Edit and RichEdit have in common, bit of the stretch.  The end of the article ups the ante by talking about the "predefined edit control window procedure" :)  I've always worked from the assumption that there is only one and have never been disappointed.

Comment: @HansPassant "I've always worked from the assumption that there is only one and have never been disappointed." totally agree :). I too believed the same till I read this. And  then the whole return `TRUE`/`FALSE` thing. I mean this has been on MSDN for years now, so I am sure its not a documentation bug.

Comment: builtin user32 controls procedures are special in a sense that they are exposed via handle-like values to provide A/W duality, and not real function pointers. You have to use CallWindowProc() to call it. And yes, it is class-specific in a sense that it only applies to builtin controls, I don't think you can create such handles from outside.

Comment: @bunglehead i though so (as mentioned in point 2). Can you please elaborate a bit? or provide any pointers where I can find more info?

Comment: Maybe you should just stop worrying about it.

Comment: @subdeveloper, builtin classes are using winproc handles instead of plain function pointers, I don't know how I can elaborate more on this. You can easily write some tests to see what I mean.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs Hans and bunglehead, I'll validate what bunglehead said. For now leaving the question open just in case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments and research, it looks like this is to do with slightly inaccurate documentation on MSDN. Though I am sure folks at Microsoft can add some sense to it, maybe something related to internal implementation.